# UIScreen bounds are not correct in Snapshop testing

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, gui-testing

I'm trying to use [swift-snapshot-testing](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) for snapshot testing. It works find in most cases, but I have one big issue.
for example here is my test

```
func test_onboarding_iPhone13() {
    let vc = OnboardingViewController()
    assertSnapshot(matching: vc, as: .image(on: .iPhone13(.portrait)), record: true)
}
```

So it should run the test on iPhone 13, and on that `vc` I use `UIScreen.main.bounds` to calculate some sizes, and works well when the test is not running, but in the snapshop test, the value of `UIScreen.main.bounds` will be equal to

```
(lldb) p UIScreen.main.bounds
(CGRect) $R0 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 480))
```

Which is not correct at all

when I run the app in simulation (no testing), here is the size

```
(lldb) p UIScreen.main.bounds
(CGRect) $R0 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 390, height = 844))
```

Do I do something wrong? anyone had the same experience? Thanks

Comment: can you please write which size you expect? it will help to tackle your issue

Comment: Thank you for your response,  yes sure, will the same device on the simulation (no testing) the size is (width = 390, height = 844), updated the first post as well